# Can I download a jar file from maven central using maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a dependency problem with maven. I used to have saxon 8.7 that is located on maven central. Then, I had to upgrade to the latests saxon-b 9.1.0.0 which is only partially on maven central.

This is a snippet of my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The first artifact 'saxon' is available on maven central, but the secon 'saxon-dom'. Here is the [artifact I want](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.saxon%7Csaxon%7C9.1.0.8%7Cjar).

Can I tell maven to download the "jar" file or am I obliged to download the jar and publish it locally on my maven repo to use it as a dependency?

Comment: See: http://saxon.sourceforge.net and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did not expect to resolve this so easily :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
  <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0.8</version>
  <classifier>dom</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Basically, I can get the dependencies that are "attached" to the 'saxon' artifact using the ***classifier*** tag. Did not know about this and I found out that the tag existed when I searched for 'saxon' on [Sonatype repository (which is quite good)](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~saxon). It gave me the dependency snippet above.

Reference : http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: I am confused a little bit. Check this [search](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~saxon-dom), it is this that the OP needs. And the link you gave doesn't shown any pom snippet with the classifier.

Comment: I gave the snippet, I only gave the maven POM full reference. All the jars are named "saxon-x.jar", I only added the <classifier> to tell maven to use it as a "name". So in the example above, it becomes "saxon-dom.jar". This way I got maven to download the jar files that are part of the the main "saxon" artifact.

Answer (score 1):

If the required version is not in the repo, then yes you need to do one of the following alternatives

1. Search for a public repo containing the required version of jar. And add the repo to your `pom.xml` file. OR
2. Download it manually, and install it locally on your machine, to help the project build completely.